# I'm looking for an incredibly obscure word meaning "obscure / holy / hidden away"

Tags: obscure-terms

I am fairly certain it starts with the letter 'd', but if not, it at least has that letter in it.

Other words that describe it: recondite / cryptic / secret / arcane / "not many people are allowed access."

A friend told me what it was it a ways back. Apparently it was the word-of-the-day on dictionary.com once. (I have not been able to find it there...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esconced or niched come to mind, but they're not even credibly obscure. Adytum, perhaps?

Comment: Thank you! Adytum was the word I was looking for! I would vote you up had I the reputation. Maybe it's not the most obscure word, but at least it's not in Chrome's dictionary...

Answer (score 4):

Maybe:

- ***[Delphian](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/delphian)***?
- Obfuscated.
- Esoteric
- Occult
- Adumbrated ("[3. To disclose partially or guardedly.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/adumbrate)")
- Recondite
- Abstruse

Comment: _Occult_ has most of those meanings.

Comment: The word was adytum, but I really do appreciate this list. I'll remember to use adumbrated some time. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a possibility - [delitescent](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/delitescent)?

Comment: Hello sir, may I enquire... where/how did you find this word? are you a Latin scholar?

Comment: Obscure words starting with D: http://www.kokogiak.com/logolepsy/ow_d.html

Comment: This is an interesting word that I've not heard of before! I'll have to keep it in mind. @Spehro found the word: adytum.

Answer (score 1):

*[ar·cane](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/arcane)* ärˈkān/ adj.
**1**. understood by few; mysterious or secret.

*syn*.
***[recondite](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/recondite)*** (rĕk′ən-dīt′, rĭ-kŏn′dīt′) *adj*.
**1**. Not easily understood; abstruse. See Synonyms at ambiguous.
**2**. Concerned with or treating something abstruse or obscure: recondite scholarship.
**3**. Concealed; hidden.

[vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/recondite) on *recondite*:

> It's rather difficult to penetrate the meaning of recondite. Fitting, because it's an adjective that basically means hard for the average mind to understand.
>   
>   If it's really hard to comprehend, then it's safe to say it's recondite. In the same family as "abstruse," "esoteric" and "totally deep, man," recondite is a very serious word that you could use to describe obscure philosophy books, high level mathematical theory, and the series finale of The Sopranos — you know, things that make your brain hurt.

Comment: Both those words were given in the question as synonyms of the elusive word.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Pass the down votes, they can be useful to others. :)